# Delphi and Indy - How can I send something from IdTCPServer to a specific IdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I started playing with Indy 10 (from Delphi XE3) and TCP connections recently. I already could, with your help (special thanks to Remy Lebeau), build a simple server application for manage client connections (see here [Delphi - Simple TCP client / server using Indy to check clients status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208595/delphi-simple-tcp-client-server-using-indy-to-check-clients-status)). I am using a listbox to add connected clients. See the code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Host: String;
begin
  Host := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP));
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    Procedure
    begin
      ListBox.Itens.Add(Host);
      Log('Connected - ' + Host);
      With TCPServer.Contexts.LockList Do
      Try
        StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := 'Connected Clients: ' + IntToStr(Count);
      Finally
        TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
    end
  );
end;
```

Now I am trying to send a "hello" from server to a specific client in the list. My idea was to click to select a client hostname in the listbox, then click a button to send the message. But what I am researching is that things are not so easy as I am thinking...

Please, can some Indy expert point me the correct direction (with Indy 10)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hello would most commonly be sent from the `OnConnect` event, where you have direct access to the `TIdContext` for the client that connected.

That being said, if you want to send data to a specific client from outside of the server events, then you need to keep track of the `TIdContext` object for the desired client, or look for it in the server's `Contexts` list.  In this particular example, you can store the `TIdContext` object pointer in the ListBox itself, then retrieve it when needed, eg:

```
procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Host: String;
begin
  Host := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP));
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      ListBox.Items.AddObject(Host, AContext);
      Log('Connected - ' + Host);
      With TCPServer.Contexts.LockList Do
      Try
        StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := 'Connected Clients: ' + IntToStr(Count);
      Finally
        TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Host: String;
begin
  Host := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP));
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      Index: Integer;
    begin
      Index := ListBox.Items.IndexOfObject(AContext);
      if Index <> -1 then
        ListBox.Items.Delete(Index);
      Log('Disconnected - ' + Host);
      With TCPServer.Contexts.LockList Do
      Try
        StatusBar.Panels[0].Text := 'Connected Clients: ' + IntToStr(Count);
      Finally
        TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
      end;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfrmMain.sendButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
  Ctx: TIdContext;
begin
  Index := ListBox.ItemIndex;
  if Index = -1 then Exit;
  Context := TIdContext(ListBox.Items.Objects[Index]);
  // use Context as needed...
end;
```

Granted, this is not the safest approach, but it will get you started.  Things you need to consider:

1. A client might disconnect and free its `TIdContext` object before you have removed it from the ListBox.  You should make sure the object is still in the server's `Contexts` list before using it.
2. Sending unsolicited data from a button event (or any other non-server event) is not thread-safe.  Your communications can become corrupted if you send data to the same client from other threads, in particular from the server's events, without syncing the threads.  You *should* be managing the communications from within the server events only. If you need to send data from outside the events, it is safer to put the data into a per-client thread-safe queue, and then have the `OnExecute` event send the content of the queue when it is safe to do so.  I have posted examples of that many times before in several different forums, so it should not be hard to find them online.
3. The `OnDisconnect` event is not a good place to look up client details, like its hostname. You should do that in the `OnConnect` and/or `OnExecute` event and then cache the value for later use.  You can use the `TIdContext.Data` property for that purpose, or derive a new class from `TIdServerContext` and set the server's `ContextClass` property before activating the server.

Comment: thank you again for your help and tips! It's almost 1 am here, I will try your tips tomorow and let you know...

Comment: I see another potential problem. What will happen when your TCPServer sends mesage to TCPClient and it is not expecting it? It has been some time when I was fidling with Indy but if my memory serves me corectly the TCPClient isn't always listening for inbound trafic like TCPServer is. So it can't recieve message from TCPServer unless you previously told it to do so. I remember having this problems in one of my projects so I ended up with combination of TCPClient and TCPServer both on client and server side of my software.

Comment: @SilverWarior this workaround is not necessary if the client uses a receive thread, using the same connection, which continuously listens for incoming data on the socket. This is how the Indy Telnet client (TIdTelnet) works.

Comment: Yes, if the server is allowed to send unsolicited data to clients then the clients need to be listening for inbound data at all times, whether by thread or by timer. You don't need a second connection for it, a single connection will work fine, as long as the communication protocol supports it.